# CKAN upload custom format tsv on schedule

Tags: url, upload, scheduled-tasks, ckan

I am trying to upload custom formatted data files from the UK climate site e.g.[this file](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/pub/data/weather/uk/climate/stationdata/aberporthdata.txt). There are 5 lines of metadata and 1 header line.

1) Can CKAN preprocess the file according to a format I give it so that only data are picked up. Possibly saving the metadata in the description?

I would prefer a frontend option because I want users to be able to do this themselves.

2) Is it possible to have a dataset uploaded automatically once the url is entered. I currently have to go to the manage -> datastore page and click on upload to datastore to have the data populated.

3) Can the dataset be updated at a regular interval?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Not currently.  Doing ETL on incoming data is something that is discussed a lot recently, so it may happen soon.
2. You shouldn't have to manually trigger a load into datastore.  Is this when creating a new resource, or if you're editing an existing resource? When editing a resource I believe it is only triggered if the URL changes.
3. You can use https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest to have data pulled into CKAN on a regular schedule - there are harvesters for various different stores, so it depends on where it is updated from.